# Magento store switcher contains bug?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, stores

I am trying to remove the language[image] switcher and trying to add store switcher to the header, however store switcher doesn't show up tried all possible things
Please help...

Comment: What did you tried? Can you show your code